# RESTful cakephp API - Different returning JSON - Browser vs AJAX

Tags: json, api, cakephp

I have setup my first API based system using cakephp. I have set it up so within the browser for example: domain.com/cms/blogs returns the JSON as follows:

> [{"id":"2","name":"Sample News Item 002","slug":

etc

HOWEVER as soon as I call this same URL via AJAX the code is coming though as

`{"blogs":[{"id":"2","name":"Sample News Item 002","slug":` etc

I'm assuming it's because in my view I have set the code as

```
echo json_encode($blogs);
```

But when it's called via JAX it uses a different view?  Is this correct and if so what is the solution so the ajax returns the same as my browser view?

I just tried to add the same view code (**echo json_encode($blogs);**) within *app/View/Blogs/json/index.ctp* but it didn't seem to make a difference.

// CONTROLLER CODE

```
    public function index($slug = NULL) 
    {
    $this->layout = null;
    $this->response->type('json');

        $cond = array('Blog.online' => 1);

        if(isset($slug))
        {
            $cond[] = array('Blog.slug' => $slug);
            $this->set('slug', $slug);
        }


        $blogs = $this->Blog->find('all', array('conditions' => $cond));
        $blogs = Set::extract('/Blog/.', $blogs);
        $this->set(array(
            'blogs' => $blogs,
            '_serialize' => array('blogs')
        ));

        return json_encode($blogs);
}
```

Thankyou

Comment: can youp put your controller code

Comment: Yes, this has been added. Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not rendering your view file. your controller is just returning the json data here.

Just add `$this->autoRender = false;` in your controller code.

Hope this helps.